# Setting up local DNS connected to a dynamic DNS service like NoIP

Tags: dns, dynamic-dns

I've been trying to set this up for a while now and I'm just not sure what to do at all. I was following this tutorial here on setting up your own DNS server https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/dns-configuration.html

But I'm not sure where I should be putting links to services inside my network. Do I replace all the example.com's with myname.noip.org's, and then are those addresses pointing to my internal 192.168.1.x addresses or should they point to my global IP addresses.

Any help or links to good tutorials would be fantastic, I just don't know where too look at the moment and I feel like I've already looked through all of the first page google tutorials. I just can't get the concepts in my head right.

Happy to add any more information you may need.
Thanks!